How to trigger KDE trash cleanup?
I have enabled auto-delete files older than 30 days in Dolphin trash settings.
See https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kio/kcontrol5/trash/.
However, the check seems never to happen. 1+ year old files still exist in the trashcan.
I have read here (https://discuss.kde.org/t/wastebin-auto-delete-doesnt-work/3111) that the check only happens when a file is trashed using the KDE API.
So I tried to manually trash a file in Dolphin (instead of using gio trash) and it still does not work.
Any ideas?
Trashing a file older than 30 days doesn't delete it. It is just moved to trash (as expected).
I expect the 30 days count beginning the day when the file was moved to trash. This info is available in Dolphin.

What if (via dolphin) you trash a file that is actually older than 30 days ? Is this file actually deleted ?

No, I updated my question.

Got it. In fact, the check is triggered and files in trash for more than 30 days get deleted.
Except some really old files, that must have been there before I changed configuration to enable auto-deleting old files in trash.
So the setting is just non-retroactive.
